# How to reset the attachments store?

Tags: corda, production

I replaced a signed `contracts.jar` on my production node with another signed `contracts.jar` containing 1 additional contract and states.
Now I get the following error:

```
Failed net.corda.core.transactions.MissingContractAttachments: Cannot find contract attachments for com.cordacodeclub.contracts.LockableTokenContractnull. See https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html#debugging
```

You can see it live by going to http://54.216.255.188:8080 and pressing "Reset". The `LockableTokenContract` mentioned in the error message is an old contract that was present in the previous signed jar.

I am ok to lose all the production data as this is still a test arrangement. So I hid the `persistence.mv.db` and `persistence.trace.db`, to no avail.

So my question is how can I start afresh by:

- resetting my vault and the attachment store
- keeping my testnet certificates

EDIT:
Here is the start log of the node:

```
Sep 27 18:48:17 ip-172-31-6-121 corda[86960]: --- Corda Open Source 4.4 (21e8c4f) -------------------------------------------------------------
Sep 27 18:48:17 ip-172-31-6-121 corda[86960]: Logs can be found in                    : /opt/corda/logs
Sep 27 18:48:34 ip-172-31-6-121 corda[86960]: Advertised P2P messaging addresses      : 54.216.255.188:10002
Sep 27 18:48:34 ip-172-31-6-121 corda[86960]: RPC connection address                  : 0.0.0.0:10003
Sep 27 18:48:34 ip-172-31-6-121 corda[86960]: RPC admin connection address            : 0.0.0.0:10004
`Sep 27 18:48:41 ip-172-31-6-121 corda[86960]: Loaded 12 CorDapp(s)                    : CorDapp corda-updates-core version 1.0 by com.r3 with licence Unknown, Workflow CorDapp: Slot Machine Flows version 1 by vendor Corda Code Club with licence Apache License, Version 2.0, Workflow CorDapp: Confidential Identities Workflows version 1 by vendor Corda Open Source with licence Apache License, Version 2.0, CorDapp bn-onboarder-app version 2.0 by net.corda.businessnetworks with licence Unknown, CorDapp corda-updates-app-states version 1.0 by com.r3 with licence Unknown, CorDapp business-network-membership-service-states version 1.0 by com.r3 with licence Unknown, Contract CorDapp: Accounts SDK - States and Contracts version 1 by vendor R3 with licence Apache 2, CorDapp corda-updates-transport version 1.0 by com.r3 with licence Unknown, Contract CorDapp: Slot Machine contracts version 1 by vendor Corda Code Club with licence Apache License, Version 2.0, CorDapp business-network-membership-service version 1.0 by com.r3 with licence Unknown, Contract CorDapp: Accounts - Flows version 1 by vendor R3 with licence Apache 2, CorDapp corda-updates-app version 1.0 by com.r3 with licence Unknown
Sep 27 18:48:41 ip-172-31-6-121 corda[86960]: Node for "TESTNET_B9lab" started up and registered in 25.45 sec
Sep 27 18:48:41 ip-172-31-6-121 corda[86960]: SSH server listening on port            : 2222
Sep 27 18:48:41 ip-172-31-6-121 corda[86960]: Running P2PMessaging loop
```

Comment: Were both jars signed by the same signer? Using signature constraints, upgrading CorDapps should be seamless. But if it was different signers, then Corda won’t recognize the new jar as an upgrade. You can always reset your node by deleting H2 database files, if devMode = true; it will rebuild the necessary tables on startup.

Comment: Yes, both were signed with the same key: after each jar-packaging, I confirmed it with `jarsigner`. My `devMode = false`. Isn't deleting the `persistence.*` the same as deleting the H2 db files?

Comment: Yes, persistence.* are the DB files. Any other error messages in the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big oof! I had different versions of `contracts.jar` on my 2 nodes. Both signed apparently...
Putting the same one on both ends solved it for me.